# Stopping a threaded sound loop in Clojure

Tags: clojure, javax.sound.sampled

I have a threaded looping sound clip:

```
(def f
  (future
    (let [sound-file (java.io.File. "/path/to/file.wav")
          sound-in (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/getAudioInputStream sound-file)
          format (.getFormat sound-in)
          info (javax.sound.sampled.DataLine$Info. javax.sound.sampled.Clip format)
          clip (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/getLine info)]
      (.open clip sound-in)
      (.loop clip javax.sound.sampled.Clip/LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY))))
```

The problem is that when I try to kill the thread:

```
(future-cancel f)
```

it doesn't stop the clip, which plays forever. I found that the only way to stop it was to call `(.stop clip)` explicitly. My question: what would be the best/idiomatic way of doing this? I'm pretty new to Clojure, so I only experimented with `future` so far, but maybe an `agent` would be better suited in this context?

**Update:** given that the `.loop` function is non-blocking (as was discussed below), I simplified my design by getting rid of the initial `future`:

```
(defn play-loop [wav-fn]
    (let [sound-file (java.io.File. wav-fn)
          sound-in (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/getAudioInputStream sound-file)
          format (.getFormat sound-in)
          info (javax.sound.sampled.DataLine$Info. javax.sound.sampled.Clip format)
          clip (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/getLine info)]
      (.open clip sound-in)
      (.loop clip javax.sound.sampled.Clip/LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY)
      clip))
```

along with a controlling `atom`:

```
(def ^:dynamic *clip* (atom nil))
```

with which I start the loop:

```
(when (nil? @*clip*)
  (reset! *clip* (play-loop "/path/to/file.wav")))
```

and stop it:

```
(when @*clip*
  (future (.stop @*clip*) ; to avoid a slight delay caused by .stop
          (reset! *clip* nil)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
(def f
  (future
    (let [sound-file (java.io.File. "/path/to/file.wav")
          sound-in (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/getAudioInputStream sound-file)
          format (.getFormat sound-in)
          info (javax.sound.sampled.DataLine$Info. javax.sound.sampled.Clip format)
          clip (javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem/getLine info)
          stop (fn [] (.stop clip))]
      (.open clip sound-in)
      (.loop clip javax.sound.sampled.Clip/LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY)
       stop)))

(def stop-loop @f)
(stop-loop)
```

Comment: I don't get it... `(.loop ...)` will run forever, so how does stop ever get called?

Comment: Is it? I think loop is asynchronous isnt it?

Comment: @Ankur That works very well, thanks! Just to make sure I understand: this is an example of a closure, right? I find it is a very elegant solution (way more, IMHO than the convoluted OOP-based equivalent construct I can imagine in its place).

Comment: Exactly.. you needed a way to stop the audio and that is done using a function as return value of the future. The function close over the clip object (aka closure)

Comment: If .loop is asynchronous then that code doesn't need to happen in a future, does it?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't .. until there is some code in between which takes time.. which doesn't seems to be any in existing code

Comment: Not familiar with java audio...I assumed loop was blocking because of the future!

Comment: @Kevin I didn't think of that: you mean that simply calling it would spawn a thread in itself? How would I verify that?

Comment: It will call the underlying audio system API (OS level) which handle the looping so that your code can continue to execute

Comment: So just to make it clear: it *does* need to be run in a `future`, right?

Comment: Uhh...it does NOT need to be in a future, because the loop method is not blocking. The only reason the accepted answer works is because loop doesn't block (and therefore never needed to be in a thread in the first place). Consider this. If loop was blocking, then dereferencing the future here `(def stop-loop @f)` would also block forever.

Comment: @Kevin I think you're right after all: I tried running a threadless version of the function, and it does fine. As an aside, I think I'm currently a little outside my level of comfort, as I've been spending the afternoon trying to make sense of double-dereferencing a `future` stored in an `atom`.. I didn't intend my small project to become complex so rapidly! :-)

Comment: I have updated my initial question: please tell me if it doesn't make sense.